# Batch Windows: get last two folders before file name

Tags: windows, batch-file

I'm currently trying to rename a file in a subfolder appending both the his subfolders name, the subfolder name immediately above in the path, and current date.
This is the full path:

```
C:\USER_VALIDATION\INPUT\GRUPPO_FARLOCCO\AIX\merge.csv
```

I'd like that merge.csv become GRUPPO_FARLOCCO_AIX_17072020.csv
I need to do that in a batch file and in a FOR, because I need to repeat this renaming action in every subfolder

```
C:\USER_VALIDATION\INPUT\.
```

Up until now I can get to this result: `AIX_17072020.csv` with the following code

```
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
  FOR %%@ in ("merge*") DO (
    Echo Ren: ".\%%~n#\%%@" "%%~n#_%date:/=%%%~x@"
        Ren "%%@" "%%~n#_%date:/=%%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)
Pause&Exit
```

Now, I can get `\USER_VALIDATION\INPUT\GRUPPO_FARLOCCO\AIX\` with  `%%~p@`  but I cannot just get only the last two folders. I think it could be effective just remove the first 23 characters and replace the remaining two "" with "_" but I can't do it.
Can someone please help?
Thank you!

Comment: And if you fully understand that link, you should be able to adapt that code to get the parent folder and the Grandparent folder.

Comment: @Squashman 
I can get the right folder name with " for %%I in (..) do set ParentFolderName=%%~nI%%~xI" but immediately after the variable is empty (it turns my echo on when I try to print it), and if I place %%~nI%%~xI in front of my ren I get nothing. I think this is because I put that on my second FOR. Can you give advice?

Answer (score 0):

This is the working code:

```
@Echo OFF
FOR /D /R %%# in (*) DO (
    PUSHD "%%#"
  FOR %%@ in ("merge*") DO (
for %%I in (..) DO Ren "%%@" "%%~nI%%~xI_%%~n#_%date:/=%%%~x@"
    )
    POPD
)

Pause&Exit
```

Thanks for the share @squashman